Decoding BER file using ASN.1TOOLS containing multiple records
I am trying to decode BER files
here is my code:
#decoding function
def decode_ber_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        binary_data = file.read()
        try:
            decoded_data = asn1_spec.decode('CallDetailRecord', binary_data)
            #decoded_data is a dictionary containing byte strings
            decoded_data = {key: value.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(value, bytes) else value for key, value in decoded_data.items()}
            return decoded_data
        except Exception as e:
            return {"error": str(e)}


directory_path = 'msc_binary'
asn1_spec = asn1tools.compile_files('msc_schema.asn', codec='ber')

decoded_records = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith('.ber'):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        record = decode_ber_file(file_path)
        if isinstance(record, dict) and "error" not in record:
            decoded_records.append(record)

# Convert list of dictionaries to DataFrame
df_msc = pd.DataFrame(decoded_records)


I am only getting 1 record per file, while it should contain many records.

If the issue is the content of a file not as expected, please consider reducing your post to one representative file, skipping the file census and the iterating. From [ask], it is generally best to not post your code as is but only the part that troubles you, in order to get answers.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
